# How to trim all the lines in a file in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am able trim all the contents in file

```
$lines=(Get-Content $BaselineFile)

foreach ($line in $lines) { $line= $line.Trim() }
```

But how to put back the result in same file. ($Baselinefile)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a nice 2 liner:

```
$lines=(Get-Content $BaselineFile) | foreach{ $_.Trim()}  
$lines > $BaselineFile
```

Comment: Thanks buddies.Both are great answers and gave me a clue to make it as a single liner. "(Get-Content $BaselineFile) | foreach{ $_.Trim()} | Out-File  $BaselineFile"

Answer (score 8):

This is more concise:

```
(gc $BaseLineFile)| % {$_.trim()} | sc $BaseLineFile
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$lines=(Get-Content $BaselineFile)
$newcontent = foreach ($line in $lines) { $line.Trim()} 
$newcontent | out-file $BaselineFile
```